# How to render a list of items fetched from an asynchronous API call

Tags: angular

I'm facing a basic Angular (Javascript) issue. I'm making a call to an API that will give me the list of some roles such as Admin, Viewer, Guest etc. I want to display the same list on the UI.

Things i tried:

**TS:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.roles$ = this.populateRoles();
  }

  populateRoles(): any {
    let role = [];
    this._authService.getRoletList().subscribe((res: any) => {
      role = res.roles.map((item: any) => {
        return item.roleName;
      });
      console.log('role list', role); // printing correct roles
    });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<li *ngFor="let item of roles$ | async">
  {{ item }}
</li>
```

The list on UI is empty even though console log is printing the correct list. Please point out the mistake.

Comment: roles$ should be an Observable?, but populateRoles return void atm, maybe changing to something like 
return this._authService.getRoletList().pipe(map(
  // your code
));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of using the `async` pipe is for subscribing to an observable reactively. The logic you have on ngOnInit is correct but the problem is `populateRoles` does not return an observable, it returns nothing, is `void`.

Since you are using `async` pipe, you should not subscribe manually in your code, you could make the following changes:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.roles$ = this.populateRoles();
}

populateRoles(): Observable<yourTypeGoesHere> {
   return this._authService.getRoletList().pipe(
     map(res => res.roles.map(item => item.roleName)),
     tap((data => console.log('items: ', data)))
   );
}
```

Notice how `populateRoles` does not subscribe and it returns an observable. If you need to handle some logic from the observable then simply `pipe` it and handle whatever it needs to do there.